# Akka Actors/Cluster - Monitor meta events

Tags: scala, reflection, akka, cluster-computing, actor

Is it possible in Akka Actors or, by extension, Akka Cluster to monitor meta events? With meta events I refer to events such as:

- Actor sending a message to another actor
- A message arriving in another actor
- A message being received (starting to be handled)
- A new actor spawning
- An exisiting actor terminating (with reason)
- ...

I would like to write a piece of software/code that people can easily add to their own Akka Actor/Cluster projects (e.g. by just adding an import or replacing the ActorRefFactory they use for example). This piece of code/software (could be an actor itself) would then receieve all meta events of the project and could process them in some fashion. For example calculating some metrics or generating a visualization.

To recapitulate the question clear; how do I make sure meta events exist within the system, how do I then gather them in one place and how do I do this without requiring the programmer to change up his/her whole program.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: There are projects that do most of what you are looking for (Lightbend's telemetry can do most if not all of it).  Generally it would involve registering an extension in the `ActorSystem`, and then having a fairly deep knowledge of Akka internals to hook in the right places.

Comment: You refer to this? https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Extension.html

Comment: Yep.  That said, lightbend telemetry also uses a Java Agent for a lot of things.